# Error while Creating directory using mkdir and loop in python

Tags: python, file, directory, mkdir

I wanted to create directories of the definite names on python. I used jupyter and in the first case it worked perfectly well.

I am using a window system `mkdir suraj` It creates a directory named suraj.

Since this worked, I set up a loop to create 10 directories.

```
for i in range(1,10):
    x= "dir"+str(i)
    mkdir(x)
```

Error is :-

```
NameError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-5-9da2633c1170> in <module>
      1 for a in d:
----> 2     mkdir(a)

NameError: name 'mkdir' is not defined
```

Why mkdir is not defined in the name although it successfully created a director in the above command.

Image of Code with Error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there!

Basically `mkdir` is a function within `OS` module. So, unless you did not import `mkdir` explicitly, it's gonna raise a `NameError`.

So, the right code would be-

```
from os import mkdir
for i in range(1,10):
    x = "dir"+str(i)
    mkdir(x)
```